# Windows not finding HP Smart Array P410? (Windows 7 Ultimate, Server 2012, 2012 R2) HP EliteDesk 800 G1 SFF

Tags: drivers, bios, firmware, hp-proliant

### Windows not finding HP Smart Array P410? (Windows 7 Ultimate, Server 2012, 2012 R2) HP EliteDesk 800 G1 SFF

I have got myself an **HP EliteDesk 800 G1 SFF** (i5-4590 @ 3.3GHz, 8GB RAM) to use as a home server and i have installed a RAID card (**HP Smart Array P410** w/ 512mb Cache) along with 4 Seagate 1TB drives that have been configured in a RAID 5 array. (Logical 3TB drive, fault tolerance of 1 drive)

The logical drive does not show up at all in Windows and neither does the card (**Device Manager / Disk Manager**)? I am unable to install any drivers for it because the installation program cannot find the hardware or says the OS is not supported? (**This was the case for Windows 7 Ultimate, Server 2012, Server 2012 R2**).

**I have been to the HP site and looked for the relevant drivers, software etc and nothing that I have found has helped at all!**

> It has been suggested that i take a look in the BIOS to check if there
> is anything that could be stopping the card being detected by Windows,
> so i will add that to my list.

I have since done this, see update.

#### UPDATE

So i have had a play with the BIOS settings and have found that the **option ROM** setting was enabled on the PCI slot that the card was installed in, i turned this off and at one point the card was found in Device Manager (it has since gone missing). **I was unable to see the logical drive in both computer and Disk Management...** I have been told that sometimes these HP cards will not work outside of a HP ProLiant server but I don't believe that in a HP Desktop this would be the case. (Its all HP!?)

#### UPDATE 2

I took the card into work today and decided to plug it into a Dell machine and without any messing around the card was recognised straight away and i could see the logical drive and the card in Device Manager?! Sounding like a Firmware issue now.

If anyone has any suggestions that would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Does it show in Device Manager?

Comment: @qasdfdsaq Unfortunately not, i can access the card BIOS and configure it however it does not show in device manager along with the logical drive in disk management.

Comment: Curious, have you checked everywhere in device manager? Even without the drivers it should still show up as unidentified device, basic controller, or *something*. Alternatively, try a Linux live disk and see if that's detecting the card with e.g. `lshw` or `lspci`

Comment: looked everywhere yes, there is nothing to suggest that the card is being picked up which is bizarre... I will give that a go when I get home tonight, do you reckon there is anything i should check in the BIOS?

Comment: Did you actually configure the array on this particular machine? i.e. can you enter the card's pre-boot configuration (i.e. RAID BIOS)?

Comment: Yes i can access the RAID BIOS, the card was configured in the current machine yes.

Comment: Very odd. Although it's vaguely possible HP have deliberately blacklisted the device working on a HP-non-server, I'd still check under Linux.

Comment: I can't see why they would do that but who knows! I will take a look on Linux and post back what i find. Do HP tend to blacklist devices from working on non HP server hardware?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31349/discussion-between-woolnut-and-qasdfdsaq).